# Help me find an XML editor

Tags: xml

I am searching for a few days now to find the suitable XML editor.
After realizing that many of them don't do a lot more than eclipse the only difference being in the price, I started to use eclipse to edit the xml directlly. 
So I am curios if any of you know actually a way to edit xml files using a tree/grid view that displays errors on it. I guess the most important thing is that it should be able to suggest solutions in completing data on tree view by checking the schema. 
I would even be interested in a different editor as long as it delivers th

If any of you have any suggestions please help me!

Comment: On what OS you you want it?

Answer (score 3):

[XML Notepad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905339.aspx) is a handy tool.

Answer (score 3):

Since others have answered anyway:

- [First Object XML Editor](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm) is very fast & lightweight.
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (optionally with the [xml tools plugin](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#X)) is my editor of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try Emacs [nXML mode](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/). Emacs has everything, and it loads marginally faster than Eclipse ;)

Answer (score 0):

what about [liquid xml editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-editor.aspx), its a bit  more heavy but I love the GUI, very neat and tidy. or checkout http://www.xml-editor.info for more xml editors, good luck.